# Replacing the synthesized Equals() of C# record struct

Tags: c#, struct, record, equality

#### In short:

Is there any way to provide my own `Equals( object? )` method for a `record struct` instead of being stuck with the one automagically generated by the compiler?

#### Note:

This question has nothing to do with replacing the automatically generated `MyRecord.Equals( MyRecord )` method, which is trivially doable; This question is specifically about replacing the `MyRecord.Equals( Object? )` method inherited from `Object`, which is a whole different story.

#### Background:

If I want to override `Equals( object? )` in plain old `class` and `struct`, I am free to do so; however, I cannot do it with `record`; the IDE says "Member with the same signature is already declared", while the compiler gives "error CS0111: Type 'Color' already defines a member called 'Equals' with the same parameter types".

A quick look at official Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record) says that this is by design.

#### The Question:

Does anyone know any workaround to this?

(Besides just never using `record` and forfeiting all of its convenience.)

Comment: _"To somewhat mitigate this problem, in every class that I have the need to override object.Equals( object? ) I make sure to declare it with [System.Obsolete] so that it cannot be accidentally invoked."_ - personally I would try to write a analyzer to achieve this goal.

Comment: Also can you please show the trick with the obsolete attribute - cause I was not able to make it work [with my initial attempt](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFDKnAnACgGIHteYB2ApgO4AEAsgJ4DCANgIYDOzmAlADTkBEcP7dgG5kyAEb565PARoMWzcgGNuaAAzK47cgF4AfMoB0AUQCOAV0b02SrSJRJmAFwBO5pU6p0mrcsgDeyOTB5ADaAPJizLj0xE7EmDwKjDzcrubE7AC6QSFQAMzkuABuxC4uAJbAxOQSMeRmltaYuGIAVsQeAPxF7ey5wYFIISPkaFhwk8IDo1AA7LUsxCYWVmytbdPDIQC+MwVFpeVVNRWEngDicQASLAAWtLjVHLp6M6Mf5E53LrgUJBQAHK4JwASQAtgAHWLg4jnYjAYwADyUxEhTgquEIHHsOyAA)

Comment: @GuruStron thanks for thinking along with me.  When I follow the link you provided I see that you have in fact been able to make it work; is there something I am missing?

Comment: You only get that warning about obsolete member overriding non-obsolete member, which as I have already said, needs to be suppressed.  I use `System.Obsolete` without any arguments, but whatever suits you.

Comment: What I have tried to show is that applying `Obsolete` attribute to override does not prevent the `object.Equals` from being used.

Comment: @GuruStron Okay, I am sorry, I must have not made myself clear. The problem is not with `struct`, it is with `record struct`, (also with `record class`,) and it is not caused by the obsolete attribute; the ability to add the obsolete attribute is simply my reason for wanting to redefine the compiler-synthesized `Equals( object? )` method. Which is something that the compiler does not let me do in a `record struct`.

Comment: I mean based on my attempt adding the attribute is pointless, so I asked how do you achieve your goal with it.

Comment: @GuruStron I'll be damned, I can't get it to reproduce. When invoking the `Equals( object? )` method, the compiler does not issue a warning that it has been deprecated. Maybe that's why it issues the warning when deprecating the method. There is a possibility that I carried the obsoleting habit over from Java, where it works. (I believe it does. Now I can't trust anything anymore.)  I will modify the question to remove all mentions of obsolete, since it is not crucial: the question of how can one supply their own `Equals( object? )` method still stands.

Comment: @GuruStron this is what seems to be happening: the compiler does not issue a warning when invoking an intentionally obsoleted `Equals( object? )` method, ***but*** while typing the invocation, ReSharper's auto-completion ***does*** show the method name with strike-through styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *Is there any way to provide my own `Equals(object?) method for a record struct instead of being stuck with the one automagically generated by the compiler?*

   No, it is not, as the record structs [spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/record-structs#equality-members) says:

   > The record struct includes a synthesized override equivalent to a method declared as follows:
   >
   > ```
   > public override readonly bool Equals(object? obj);
   > ```
   >
   > It is an error if the override is declared explicitly.
2. *Does anyone know any workaround to this?*

   You can try looking into some assembly weaving with something like [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody), but as far as I understand this happens after compilation, so it will not cover all possible scenarios (i.e. would not work for the same assembly usage).

   Personally I would look into dumping the `ObsoleteAttribute` approach and trying to implement [Roslyn analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/roslyn-analyzers-overview?view=vs-2022) which will handle the type mismatch problem you are trying to solve.